# Does hom. $\phi$ from abelian $G$ to $H$ imply $G\cong \ker(\phi)\oplus{\rm im}(\phi)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $G,H$ are abelian groups and $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism. Can we decompose $G$ as $G\cong \ker(\phi)\oplus{\rm im}(\phi)$? More generally, what objects can have this kind of "kernel $\oplus$ image" decomposition?

Comment: The standard counterexample is let $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, let $K$ be the subgroup generated by $2$, and let $H=G/K$ with the quotient map.

Comment: Then under what condition would the statement be true?

Comment: You could assume that $G$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$.

Comment: You can do that if and only if the map has a section.

Comment: @Christina It depends on exactly what the statement is... If you want conditions on $G$ such that *every* homomorphism $\phi : G \to H$ gives such a decomposition, see my answer below. If you want conditions on $\ker\phi$ and $\operatorname{img}\phi$ which guarantee such a decomposition, see Ben C's answer. If you're looking for something different, please specify!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many examples where this fails. See halrankard2 comment for the example $G = \mathbb{Z}/ 4 \mathbb{Z}$.

If we think only about abelian groups, this situation is where we have an exact sequence,
$$ 1 \to K \to G \to H \to 1 $$
and we want to know when it "splits" meaning $G = H \oplus K$. Such sequences are called group extensions of $H$ by $K$ and in general, they will not be split. These (up to isomorphism) are classified by the group $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(H, K)$ if you are interested in looking up some homological algebra. So you can say that every sequence splits iff $\mathrm{Ext}^1(H, K) = 0$.

Some examples of when this happens.

(1) if $H$ is a free abelian group (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^n$)

(2) if $K = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ or more generally an injective group

(3) if we replace groups here with vector spaces

Comment: I interpreted the question in a different way from you, but I think it's very likely the OP was looking for this answer. Hopefully they're both useful :)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk the OP was not clear if she was interested in the case "fix G, for all maps to H" or the case "fix $\phi$" so I think both are relevant. Good fact to know about semi-simple modules.

Comment: Small note: the map $G \to H$ in your sequence is not the same as map $\phi$ in OP's post. If given a map $\phi : G \to H$, we get a short exact sequence $1 \to \ker \phi \to G \to \operatorname{img} \phi \to 1$, where the map $\ker \phi \to G$ is the inclusion and the map $G \to \operatorname{img}\phi$ is the corestriction of $\phi$. After this translation, we can look at the Ext group to try to determine if the sequence splits.

Comment: this is true, I took the liberty of replacing $H$ by its image. Luckily if $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(H, K) = 0$ then $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(\mathrm{im}(\varphi), K) = 0$ as well.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, by the first isomorphism theorem, $G/\ker \phi \cong \operatorname{img} \phi$. Moreover, every subgroup $A$ of $G$ is the kernel of some homomorphism from $G$, namely the canonical projection $G \to G/A$. Thus, this question:

> what objects can have this kind of "kernel ⊕ image" decomposition?

Is equivalent to the following:

> which abelian groups $G$ have the property that every subgroup is a direct summand?

The answer is that an abelian group $G$ has this property if and only if $G$ is a (possibly infinite) direct sum of cyclic groups of prime order. It's a good (but not extremely easy) exercise to prove this!

More generally, if $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a left $R$-module, the following are equivalent:

1. Every submodule of $M$ is a direct summand
2. $M$ is a direct sum of simple left $R$-modules
3. $M$ is the sum of its simple submodules

Such modules are called "semisimple". What I said about about abelian groups above is the equivalence of (1) and (2) in the case that $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! But do you mean "every normal subgroup A of G is the kernel of ...."?

Comment: Sure, but remember that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal :)